# How to use sweetalert while delete in php

Tags: php, html, css

Here is my fetch data.

```
<table id="dt-opt" class="table table-lg table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>City Name</th>
        <th>Area Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Action</th> 
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php 
            $counter = 0;
            $sel_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer_details, city_mst, area_mst WHERE customer_details.CITY_ID = city_mst.CITY_ID AND customer_details.AREA_ID = area_mst.AREA_ID");
            while($sel = mysql_fetch_array($sel_query)) 
            {
        ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $sel['CUSTOMER_NAME']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $sel['CONTACT_NO']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $sel['EMAIL']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $sel['CITY_NAME']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $sel['AREA_NAME']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $sel['ADDRESS']?></td>
    <td><a href="cust_save.php?delid=<?php echo $sel['CUSTOMER_ID']?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
</tr>
<?php 
        }
?>  
</tbody>
```

Here is my delete page : `cust_save.php`

```
if(isset($_GET['delid']))
    {
        include "script/db.php"; 

        $pid = $_GET['delid'];
        echo $query = "DELETE FROM customer_details WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = $pid";
        if(mysql_query($query))
        {
            header("Location:cust_view.php?msg=Deleted");
        }
        else
        {
            header("Location:cust_view.php?msg=Failed");
        }

    }
```

When I click on delete button it show sweet alert I don't understand actually how to implement please help me.

I am using core php code I am on learning phase so if someone is here who know this answer please help to complete my homework .

Comment: Sweet Alert is a Javascript library you need to add an event listener on the on the button that triggers the sweetalert

Comment: echo $sel..; ';'

Comment: "DELETE FROM customer_details WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = $pid"; .. A hacker can delete all your customer records using sql injection attack. Use pdo with prepare statement or use mysql_real_escape_string on the $_GET variable. Never trust user input.

Answer (score 0):

Get the library of sweet alert, call it and then when u delete do this

```
  <?php
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
      echo 'setTimeout(function () { swal("Your Title","Your message","error");';
      echo '}, 1000);</script>';
    ?>
```